# Understanding ES6 Named Imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm reading through the ES6 `import` statement on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax).

I understand generally how it works, but wanting to dive deeper, I'm not understanding one aspect of the syntax.

As stated in the [MDN syntax of `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax), these are all of the different way to import code into the current module/scope:

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
var promise = import("module-name");
```

---

What I'm trying to understand is the difference between these two lines:

```
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
```

Wouldn't both of those be exactly the same? We're not importing a default `export`, therefore we have to be importing named `export`s.

---

Why are they two separate syntax definitions?

And why does the second one have this:

```
from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
```

Comment: I think they are exported in the first line and in the second line they are not exported at all.

Comment: I guess that is to show that you can specify a path to a file within a module and not only module names

Comment: @Badrush but why do they separate them into separate syntaxes if the point is that they can both `import` objects? What's so different about the second one?

Comment: I think it's because foo and bar are not exported in the second one. The first one, I'm pretty sure the file has multiple exports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
```

> Why are they two separate syntax definitions?

Probably just to illustrate the point that absolute module name can also contain a path.

Then, `"module-name"` will be resolved according to usual module resolution rules, and then `foo` and `bar` will be imported from some file contained within that module.

That way, you can get access to something which is not exported from the main file of the module.

However, many module authors consider that only exports from the module main file constitute the public API. Everything else, including file names and paths, is an implementation detail which may change in unpredictable and incompatible way with each release.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. What I don't get is what constitutes an "unexported" file. Every file can either have some named exports, or an `export default`. That's all `"module-name"` would be as well. So what's so different between `"module-name"` and some deeply nested file within `"module-name"`? They're both exporting something the same way. That's what makes me wonder why there's two separate definitions for it.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "unexported" file.  There is a main file (the one indicated by `main` property in `package.json` file, or `index.js` if that property is absent), and all the other files. When you refer to a module by module name only, it's resolved automatically to the module main file. When you refer to any other file within the module, you are on your own - you are relying on the internal file layout of the module.

Comment: So, I think the name they have chosen for this example - `"un-exported/file"` - is a bit unfortunate. Files are not being exported, only symbols defined in the files are.